# Performance advantage of discard operator

Tags: c#, variables

Lets say I have this in my C# app:

```
try{
    Somethrowingmethod();
}catch(Exception ex){
    throw new Exception("oops");
}
```

If I keep my code as it is, the compiler will (rightfully so) complain about me declaring ex but no using it.

So I should instead do this :

```
try{
    Somethrowingmethod();
}catch(Exception _){
    throw new Exception("oops");
}
```

My question is, *is there a performance gain once I do this?*

Or is it only for a clean code practice?

Comment: Which performance gain did you expect? The only thing here is that you throw new exception w/o any details from previously catched

Comment: Clean code, it means you've stated that you intend to discard the exception. You could just catch the exception without declaring it if you don't need to reference it but the whole idea is to surface the exception chain/stack rather than just throwing a new exception and discarding the stack info. There needs to be a good reason to do this.

Comment: This declares a variable of type `Exception` named `_`. It's not a discard and should emit the same  [compiler warning](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDZICYgNQA+AAgEwCMAsAFBEDMABKfQML0De19XjDRALPQCyACgCU7TtykwEATzYBfegGMIMZQAthAUQAeyuAAcYaAPYA7egH1xi+pK4LqCoA==) about the unused variable. You could `catch(Exception){ }` or since this is a catch all anyways just `catch { }` but you're not getting a performance gain from any of them.

Comment: Using `_` not only in this example but also in parsing `int.TryParse("foo", out _)` is just a syntactic sugar. Compiler will automatically create a variable etc but it doesn't affect performance in any way

Comment: Using `_` in this example isn't a discard though, so no syntactic sugar involved. Catching just the exception type is the proper way to "discard" here, and does not create a variable. But still, no performance gain from it.

Comment: The compiler does *not* complain about this code.  There is a code analysis rule that makes a *recommendation* about it, visible from green squiggles underneath ex, ought to tell you that you don't need ex at all.  Do be a bit careful about that tail wagging the dog.  Having ex around to inspect when you debug the program is rather important when you write try/catch-em-all/throw-something-else code.  Which you should never write, but the analysis feature is not smart enough to tell you that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is flawed as your example does not involve discards. Instead, it names the `Exception` variable `_` and should still emit the same warning for the unused variable. See [this SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDZICYgNQA+AAgEwCMAsAFBEDMABKfQML0De19XjDRALPQCyACgCU7TtymSpXGAgCebAL70AxhBhqAFsICiADzVwADjDQB7AHb0A+uJX0Z9ZdWVA===) example and look at the warning and the `.locals init` of the generated IL.

```
.locals init (
  [0] class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Exception
)
```

The proper way to "discard" an exception is to catch the *type* only:

```
try {
  DoSomething();
} catch (Exception) {
  //... 
}
```

This does not declare a local variable which you can verify at the above link by just erasing the `_` and looking at the updated `.locals init` section (hint: it's gone now).

Since this is catching the base exception type you could also rewrite it as:

```
try {
  DoSomething();
} catch {
  //... 
}
```

Note however, that it is *generally* a bad idea to catch-all / catch the base `Exception` type.

Back to your original inquiry though: there's no performance gain involved in any of these scenarios. *At best* a variable is elided, but a *true* discard is just syntactic sugar and a variable is still declared. This code:

```
int.TryParse("1", out _);
```

still involves a local variable of type `int`. You can see that by viewing the [same section of the IL](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDZICYgNQA+AAgEwCMAsAFBEDMABKfQML0De19XjDRALPQCyACgCU7TtymSpXNADsYAOgAqCAJ4AFCAihxhAIjIGk9APYBXGPQD6ogNwz6AX2rOgA==).

```
.locals init (
  [0] int32
)
```

But again, there's no performance gain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is super clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

or just do this

```
try{
    Somethrowingmethod();
}catch(Exception){
    throw new Exception("oops");
}
```

but there is no performance difference